Bad- Request - Request Too Long HTTP Error 400 - The size of the request header is too long
I have developed a .NET Core application and hosted it in IIS. When we log in using Microsoft Office 365, we sometimes get the "Bad Request - Request Too Long HTTP Error 400 - The size of the request header is too long" error in the Microsoft Edge browser.
I have tried:

We have cleared the cookies and tried again, but we still encounter the same issue occasionally.

We have also checked the application's Request Filter settings in the IIS server. The current values are:

Maximum Allowed Content Length (Bytes): 2147483648
Maximum URL Length (Bytes): 10241
Maximum Query String (Bytes): 20481
We doubled these values to 4247483648, 20450, and 40950, respectively. However, the issue persists.


We encountered this issue with one user. We provided that user's Azure roles and rights (groups/claims) to myself, but I could not reproduce the issue.


This issue occurs not only on a single page but also when moving from one page to another or closing a page.

Please do some research, like: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HTTP+400.+The+size+of+the+request+headers+is+too+long.

HTTP 400 Bad Request (Request Header too long) responses to HTTP requests

Based on your description, the problem seems to occur intermittently. I would like to know if this problem is the same in localhost, or if it only occurs after logging in to Microsoft Office 365? You can try using another browser(such as chrome or firefox) or using browser private mode.
